# Reloading webpage once based on the time

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code that is relevant to my question

```
<script>var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();
var minute = now.getMinutes();
var second = now.getSeconds();
if(hour <= 2){ 
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "wyd?";    
    window.reload();
}
if(hour > 2 && hour <= 3){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "xxx did nothing wrong";
}
if(hour  > 3 && hour <= 4 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "The holocaust was a hoax!";
}
if(hour  > 4 && hour <= 5 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "dogs r gr8";
}
if(hour  > 5 && hour <= 6){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "meme";
}
if(hour  > 6 && hour <= 7 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "good morning u fuckin legend";
}
if(hour > 7 && hour  <= 8){ 
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Big ol'Floofer";
}
if(hour  > 8 && hour <= 9 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Hey fucktard here's the weather";
}
if(hour  > 9 && hour <= 10 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "rip @xxxx";
}
if(hour  > 10&& hour <= 11 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "69";
}
if(hour  > 11 && hour <= 12 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Time 2 meme";
}
if(hour  > 12 && hour <= 13 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "cash me outside?";
}
if(hour  > 13 && hour <= 14 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Harambe still lives!";
}
if(hour  > 14 && hour <= 15 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "greasy randy!";
}
if(hour  > 15 && hour <= 16 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "made by @xxx";
}
if(hour  > 16 && hour <= 17 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "sponsered by busch";
}
if(hour  > 17 && hour <= 18 ){
    location.reload();
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "bork";
}
if(hour  > 18 && hour <= 19 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "sweet doggo";
}
if(hour  > 20 && hour <= 21 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "floof";
}
if(hour  > 21 && hour <= 22 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "get a good sleep u";
}
if(hour  > 22 && hour <= 23 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "bruh";
}
if(hour  > 23 && hour <= 24 ){
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "There goes ur good sleep";
}
```

I also have other lines like this, each with different times that output a different phrase between the hours of x and x. When I run the program (website) it continuously reloads the page, I am wondering how to get it so it only reloads the web page once instead of continuously like it's doing.
Ideally this is to be automated with absolutely no user input (such as a button).

Comment: firstly, your expression can simply be reduced to if(hour == 18), secondly can you provide the other code you're mentioning about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want a page that displays a message that changes every hour? If so, I'd store the `messages` in an array to keep things tidy, then just refresh the message every hour using setTimeout.

```
function checkMessage(){
  var d = new Date(), h = d.getHours(), m = d.getMinutes();
  document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = messages[h];
  setTimeout(checkMessage, (60 - m) * 1000);
}

window.addEventListener('load', checkMessage);
```

Comment: Would I create an array called messages outside the function?

Comment: Yes, or it can be inside the function if you don't need it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can not write code to after reload. To do this it needed to using Seesion Storage:

```
   if(hour  > 17 && hour <= 18 ){
      if (!sessionStorage.getItem("name"))
      {
          sessionStorage.setItem("name", "bork");
          location.reload();        
      }
   }


window.onload = function(){

    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("name");
}
```

Comment: I added this, and it continuously reloaded the page

Comment: Of course your page reloads. You need to manage the code to execute when a button click or some thing else. It executes automatically after page loads.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear, I only want the web page to reload once, there won't be any buttons on the web page. it's supposed to be a screen with 0 user interactiveness

Comment: You have a `location.reload();` after page load. It leads the page to an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, how can I get there to not be an infinite loop?

Comment: so far yes, I'm going to see if it works with other hours. I'll accept once I've verified

Comment: Thank you! But I did not ask just for accept ;) I,m going to sleep and asked that to find out if you need any help before. Good night and day.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, greatly appreciated!